# How to do some operations right after application is installed?

Tags: android

I need to write Android application (lets call it App1), that suggests to user to install another Android application (lets call it App2). If user agrees to install App2, I need App1 to do some operations right after App2 is successfully installed. What is the best way to organize this process? I was thinking about periodically check if App2 is installed, but I think that it is not the smartest way.

Comment: @Torben: nobody said anything about a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect that an app is installed, using a BroadcastReceiver.

In onCreate:

```
BroadcastReceiver appInstalledReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(action)) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        String packageName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
        // check if packageName is App2
        }
    }           
};
```

And then somewhere in onResume:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(appInstalledReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Maybe register the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: you can do that too. it's either way, not both.